# New line with subfig's subfloat

Tags: subfloats

I am using the package `subfig`. In one `subfloat`, I need to include only text (no graphics). The issue is that text does not wrap, rather, it goes out of the page.

I need to enter a new line, but adding `\linebreak` does not help, it is simply ignored.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put the text into a `\parbox{...a width...}{...your text \\ more text ...}`